# eslint-plugin-flowtype does not validate

Tags: javascript, eslint, flowtype

I am trying to configure `eslint + babel-eslint + eslint-plugin-react + eslint-plugin-flowtype`

I have the following `devDependencies` in `package.json`:

```
"babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
"eslint": "^3.10.2",
"eslint-config-airbnb": "^13.0.0",
"eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.25.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.2.0",
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^2.2.3",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^6.7.1"
```

And the following `.eslinrc`:

```
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "plugins": [
    "flowtype"
  ],
  "extends": [
    "airbnb",
    "plugin:flowtype/recommended"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "max-len": [1, 80, 2, {"ignoreComments": true}],
    "prop-types": [0],
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, { "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"] }],
    "react/prefer-stateless-function": [
      0,
      {
        "ignorePureComponents": true
      }
    ],
    "no-console": 0
  },
  "settings": {
    "flowtype": {
      "onlyFilesWithFlowAnnotation": true
    }
  }
}
```

I wrote simple code example in `App.js`:

```
function foo() {
  const a: string = 1;
  return a;
}

async function bar() {
  const b = await foo();
  return b;
}
```

If I launch `eslint src/App.js` then `eslint` does not show any messages.
If I add `"flowtype/require-return-type": 2` into `.eslintrc` then `eslint` shows:

```
error  Missing return type annotation  flowtype/require-return-type
error  Missing return type annotation  flowtype/require-return-type
✖ 2 problems (2 errors, 0 warnings)
```

But I don't understand why `const a: string = 1;` is valid.
How to enable checking type of `const a: string = 1;`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`eslint-plugin-flowtype` is **not** Flow. It is an extension to ESLint that has a collection of lint rules relevant only to Flow's additional syntax.

For example, there is a [rule](https://github.com/gajus/eslint-plugin-flowtype/blob/master/src/rules/objectTypeDelimiter.js) that lets you enforce whether to use commas or semicolons in Flow object types (e.g. `type Foo = {bar: string, baz: number}` vs `type Foo = {bar: string; baz: number}`)

However, to actually get typechecking you need to install [Flow](https://flowtype.org/), and follow the instructions there to get set up. In short, it involves making sure that you have a `.flowconfig` file at your project root, making sure that you have the `// @flow` header on all your files, and then running `flow status` from the command line (or using [Nuclide](https://nuclide.io/) or another editor with Flow support).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Do you know is it possible to use `flowtype + eslint`? I mean is it possible to `eslint` will show errors of `flowtype` when I run `eslint App.js`?

Comment: It's possible but nobody that I'm aware of has written something to show Flow results in ESLint. Personally I don't think it would be a good idea. Better to use Flow as intended and use ESLint as intended, as separate tools.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to have ESLint use Flow to validate your code, the correct plugin to use is `eslint-plugin-flowtype-errors`.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-flowtype-errors

As others wrote, `eslint-plugin-flowtype` only verifies that code with FlowType statements are syntactically correct. It does not actually do Flow type validation.

Answer (score 1):

`eslint-plugin-flowtype` [doesn't appear to have a rule to check that](https://github.com/gajus/eslint-plugin-flowtype#eslint-plugin-flowtype-rules).

The purpose of the linter-plugin is to enforce stylistic things or convention things (such as always annotating function return types), not to check types themeselves.

You'll want to run Flow itself to check that the types are actually correct.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the flowtype rule in .eslintrc file:

```
"rules": {
  "flowtype/no-types-missing-file-annotation": 0
}
```