# With eslint-plugin-flowtype, how to check if a type exist

Tags: eslint, flowtype

I enabled `eslint-plugin-flowtype` with Flow on a React project. It's work well but not perfect. I have for example the error `Missing return type annotation. (flowtype/require-return-type)` that raised for missing returned type. But I have no error when I write an unknown type. For example, writing `{dispatch: TotoType}` doesn't raise any error (`TotoType` is not declared).

#### To be more clear:

My issue is that if I write a type that does not exist (I mean `nomber` instead `number`), Flowtype eslint plugin does not return any errors. The error should be triggered whenever I use it but it is not the case :(. If I use Flow CLI on my file, I got the error like `unknown Type`. I want to have the FlowType ESlint plugin lints the same errors.

I'm using [eslint-config-evenium](https://github.com/lowik/eslint-config-evenium) configuration file that provide those rules:

```
{
    ...
    "rules": {

        "flowtype/boolean-style": [
            2,
            "boolean"
        ],
        "flowtype/define-flow-type": 1,
        "flowtype/delimiter-dangle": [
            2,
            "never"
        ],
        "flowtype/generic-spacing": [
            2,
            "never"
        ],
        "flowtype/no-primitive-constructor-types": 2,
        "flowtype/no-weak-types": 0,
        "flowtype/object-type-delimiter": [
            2,
            "comma"
        ],
        "flowtype/require-parameter-type": 2,
        "flowtype/require-return-type": [
            2,
            "always",
            {
                "annotateUndefined": "never",
                "excludeArrowFunctions": true  
            }
        ],
        "flowtype/require-valid-file-annotation": 2,
        "flowtype/semi": [
            2,
            "always"
        ],
        "flowtype/space-after-type-colon": [
            2,
            "always"
        ],
        "flowtype/space-before-generic-bracket": [
            2,
            "never"
        ],
        "flowtype/space-before-type-colon": [
            2,
            "never"
        ],
        "flowtype/type-id-match": [
            2,
            "^([A-Z][a-z0-9]+)+Type$"
        ],
        "flowtype/union-intersection-spacing": [
            2,
            "always"
        ],
        "flowtype/use-flow-type": 1,
        "flowtype/valid-syntax": 1
    },
    "settings": {
        "flowtype": {
            "onlyFilesWithFlowAnnotation": true
        }
    }
}
```

How to have ESlint generating an error for unauthorized type?
And if possible, I'll appreciate to be able to add unexisting Type to the list a authorized type.

Anyone know how to do that or if it is even possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [eslint-plugin-flowtype does not validate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40768266/eslint-plugin-flowtype-does-not-validate)

Comment: Not at all. The topic you share talks about linting a function that doesn't return a flow type. My issue is that if I write a type that does not exist (I mean `nomber` instead `number`), Flowtype eslint plugin does not return any errors. The error should be triggered when never I use it but it is not the case :(. If I use Flow CLI on my file, I got the error like `unknown Type`. I want to have the FlowType ESlint plugin lints the same errors.

Comment: The root of the issue is that you are expecting eslint-plugin-flowtype to actually run Flow, which it does not do. Without running Flow it cannot tell which types exist and which do not.

Comment: Thank you. You point out the obvious and you're right I think! I don't know how ESLint could do that without running Flow ^^. I know that my VSCode Flow plugin run a Flow server to highlight Flow code errors. But it never occurs to me that the ESlint plugin didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eslint-plugin-flowtype` only verify the syntax used to write flowtype code. It doesn't run Flowtype at all.

To have Flowtype running on your code, there are several solutions left to you:

- use [flow-bin](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-bin) to launch Flow in command line
- use [flow-bin](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-bin) + gulp to create a task that will start the Flow server:

For example:

```
gulp.task('flow', () => {
  execFile(flow, ['status'], (err, stdout) => {
    console.log(stdout);
  });
});
```

- use [gulp-flowtype](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-flowtype). It like the previous solution ([flow-bin](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-bin) + gulp) except that the gulp process can be blocked waiting for the Flowtype server to be launched and you can stop the Flowtype server at the end of the gulp process.
- use a Flowtype from your IDE. Your IDE can already providing it (aka [Nuclide](https://nuclide.io/docs/languages/flow/)) or you can find an existing plugin. For example, I use [flow-for-vscode](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-for-vscode) with VSCode.